# What encoding is needed to read this HTML file containing Spanish characters?

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding

I downloaded [this HTML file](https://archive.org/stream/labibliasagrada00socigoog/labibliasagrada00socigoog_djvu.txt) from archive.org, which is a digitilised book, written in Spanish. As such, it has plenty of accents and other unique symbols (e.g. ñ).

Now, when I open the html file in a text editor (mousepad), all text appears fine. However, when I open it using a web browser, special characters are not shown correctly. Some examples:

- á is shown as Ã¡
- ñ is shown as Ã±
- ó is shown as Ã³

etc.

I added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` to the HTML but this does not improve things. My suspicion is that I need to use a different charset option, but I have no idea which one! How can I know? I have searched for these characters (e.g. [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp)) but even Google has issues understanding them.

Comment: If it looks fine from the web server then you need to ask the web server.

Comment: UTF-8 is the correct charset, is the charset the server specifies (in HTTP header only), and your meta tag **works for me** in IE and FF. You did put it in the body of the head element, as required, right? (Chrome works for me even without the meta.)